# Number of visitors viewing current page

Tags: javascript, php, numbers, statistics

I'm not sure what would be the best way to do this, but I need to be able to show the number og guests that are viewing the current page a visitor is viewing. No who but how many.

What would be the easiest approach to do something like this? is is possible to do this without a database, but maybe with a javascript or PHP?

The output would be "There are XX people viewing this page".

**Edit:**
Could this be done by showing the number of Unique Visitors the last 15 minutes? I wouldn't be 100% accurate but would work for my purpose

Comment: I wonder how could you know when a guest has left that page.

Comment: however you have to store the `num` on the server in order to be read

Comment: http://www.usuarios-online.com/en/ any use to you?

Comment: thanks for the replies, but i want to show this nr to the visitors of that page. a remotely hosted script is not an option here

Comment: Try http://www.histats.com/

Comment: The link I sent you, will output to the screen so the users can see it.

Comment: yes, but i need the core-function for it to be able to customize and integrate this with other functions on my website

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is a stateless protocol, there's no way to determine how many
visitors are currently "online", because there simply is no way to
identify unique users except for an explicit login. It's all based on
estimations (for example the amount of requests from different IPs in
the last 10 minutes) and as useless as a hitcounter for a visitor. The
number of currently browsing users or page hits says absolutely nothing
about a site's quality.

The simpliest way is to write a script that inserts (or updates) the IP
and Time/date in a DB table. Then count the # of unique IP's and puge
the old one's. Most sites look at a 10 min. interval for this purpose;
given the nature of HTTP.

Call [the file] "userCount.php" or somthing and include it at the top
of your header so it's called on every page hit.

---

```
// ** Begin userCount.php **//

$timestamp=time();

// 10 minutes of timeout
$timeout=$timestamp-6000;

// REPLACE instead of INSERT
mysql_query("REPLACE INTO online (time,ip) VALUES
('$timestamp','$REMOTE_ADDR')
WHERE ip = '$REMOTE_ADDR')";

// purge all old users
mysql_query("DELETE FROM online WHERE time < $timeout");

// delete my own ip adress from statistic
mysql_query("DELETE FROM online WHERE ip = 'xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxx'");

$result=mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM online");
$user=mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $user;

// ** End userCount.php **//
```

This should work.

Taken from [Here](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/10170-counting-current-site-visitors)

Comment: Great script. Thanks for the great reply, but is there a way to determine how many users there have been online the latest 10 minutes then?

Comment: Yes of course, with script you remove the users when 10 minutes have passed, each time userCount is executed you are deleting from the table the ips that were inserted more than 10 min ago. do you understand? is that what you were asking?

Comment: I would use the sessionid and not the IP cause a whole company can have the same IP address but each PC in the company has a different sessionid.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way for live tracking of visitors would be to let the client of each visitor send every x seconds an ajax request to a script of you and you keep tracking of all session ids / pages in a table or text file. If a session id not posted for a certain time from a specific page remove it.

If you do it with a database. Use a table like

```
tracking
--------
sessionid (PK)
pageID (or pageURI)
last_seen (timestamp)
```

Then you can query on that table to get the amount of (more or less) current users visiting that page.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) visitors FROM tracking WHERE last_seen < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 SECONDS) GROUP BY pageID
```

But this does not work if the user has javascript disabled so its not a 100% exact solution.

Comment: how about showing the number of unique visitors the last 10 minutes? That would be a fair solution i think

Comment: Yep I agree that would be better but I tried to answer the exact question and this is "how many users are currently viewing a page".